# How to get Featured Brand

Tags: magento2, widget

I am new in Magento 2, now I am struggling about how to show featured brands lists on the main Home Page (On the top of Recently Viewed widget).

[image]

I have googled to everywhere but still have no clue how to start.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: looks like a custom CMS block. magento2 doesn't know brands

Comment: ooh okay, so I just need to create custom static layout for it right?

Comment: just use custom block or make static block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way you can do that using Magento 2 built in feature, all you need is add custom attribute is_featured on the product and then Query to the product table using filter condition.

Comment: or you could just add static block for that

Comment: yeah it think that could just a static block, thank for the suggestion